# How to add passive event listeners in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events, passive-event-listeners

To set event listener say, onKeyPress listener on some react input element, we do something like this:

```
<SomeInputElement onKeyPress={this.someListener.bind(this)}>
```

Now, what should I do to make my `someListener` passive?

Comment: According to this issue I'm not sure react support this.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6436

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always add event listeners manually in `componentDidMount` using a reference to your element. And remove them in `componentWillUnmount`.

```
class Example extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.input.addEventListener('keypress', this.onKeyPress, { passive: false });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.input.removeEventListener('keypress', this.onKeyPress);
  }

  onKeyPress(e) {
    console.log('key pressed');
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <SomeInputElement ref={ref => this.input = ref} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap your input with passive listener

```
    import {PassiveListener} from 'react-event-injector';
    <PassiveListener onKeyPress={this.someListener.bind(this)}>
        <SomeInputElement/>
    </PassiveListener>
```

Comment: I can't really find a module by the name react-event-injector. :/

Comment: Google is fast, but not so fast - https://github.com/theKashey/react-event-injector

Comment: Some strange bug with `<canvas>` element as the child. Canvas doesn't get rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to do this manually is to use refs and useEffect. In some cases useSyncExternalStore is also an option.

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
     const { current } = ref;
     if (!current) {
        return;
     }
     const abort = new AbortController();
     const { signal } = abort;
     current.addEventListener('keypress', onKeyPress, { passive: true, signal });
     return () => abort.abort();
  }, []);
  return <input {...props} ref={ref} />;
};
```